# Equivalent word combination for 'greater flexibility'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I am writing the opening line for a technical presentation and not sure of the correctness of the following statement.

> Under Display Cameras promise greater flexibility to phone manufacturers.

Are all of the following equivalent or one is better than the other in terms of grammar, syntax, etc?

- Under Display Cameras promise ***greater flexibility*** to phone manufacturers.
- Under Display Cameras promise ***more flexibility*** to phone manufacturers.
- Under Display Cameras promise ***much more flexibility*** to phone manufacturers.
- Under Display Cameras promise ***higher flexibility*** to phone manufacturers.
- Under Display Cameras promise ***superior flexibility*** to phone manufacturers.
- Under Display Cameras promise ***better flexibility*** to phone manufacturers.

Personally I think of all the third one is the most appropriate. Besides this, do any of the aforementioned statements have incorrect usage of words?

Comment: If the capitalised "Under Display Cameras" is the name of a company, you might want to use 'promise***s***'. The sentences also share the same ambiguity: whether 'to' is referring to the promise or the flexibility. Is it the cameras that will be more flexible, or the manufacturers?

Comment: If it's not the name of a company, it shouldn't be capitalized, and it should  have a hyphen: "Under-display cameras".

Comment: @WeatherVane "Under Display Cameras" is a recent technique (so for simplicity can be thought of as the name of company). I have well taken your 'promises' suggestion. It is the manufacturers who will have greater flexibility.